# How can I invoke an Objective C header file from a C++ file?

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c

I wish to call an Objective C function from a C++ file. The build fails when I include the header to the Objective C file(UnZip.h) in the C++ file(Algebra.cpp)? How do I go about it? If I remove any reference to Math.h in Algebra.cpp everything builds fine. I cannot change the name of Algebra.cpp to Algebra.mm since it's being consumed at multiple places elsewhere.

File Math.h

```
void MathFormula(const char *sourceData, const char *answer);
```

File Math.m

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "MathDocument.h"
void MathFormula(const char *sourceFile, const char *answer)
{
    NSString * sFile = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:sourceFile];
    NSString * ans = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:answer];
    MathDocument * mathDocument = [[MathDocument alloc] initWithPath:sFile];
    [mathDocument runFormula:ans];
}
```

Algebra.cpp

```
#include ...
#include Math.h
{
  ---
  const char * sourceFile = "/Users/u1/pckg.zip";
  const char * destPath = "/Users/u1";
  MathFormula(sourceFile, destPath);
  ---
}
```

Comment: When you say C++ do you mean Objective-C++ or just regular C++?

Comment: I meant regular C++.

Comment: As per my observation why you are creating different class fro single function you can create function directly in that class where you need that ?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I can directly create it in the C++ file. Regardless, if I try to import "MathDocument.h" build fails. I need to create a bridge. How do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I assume you're doing this in Xcode?)

1) "View" menu -> "Navigators" -> "Show Project Navigator" (cmd-1)

2) In the Navigator pane (left side of project window) select your file ()

3) "View" menu -> "Utilities" -> "Show File Inspector" (cmd-option-1)

4) In the Utilities pane (right side of project window) the second control from the top should be "Type" and its value is probably: "Default - C++ Source"; change that to "Objective-C++ Source".

Xcode will now build that file as an Object-C++ file. Done! (and done!)